# Best method for including images on ipad apps, concerning different models

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am getting ready to design a new iPad app, which will be locked in landscape mode. It's going to be relatively image heavy, as it will be a sales utility for hotels and resorts. There will be quite a few "hero shots" of hotels, meaning full or half screen images meant to highlight the property.

With the jump in resolution between the 2 and the 3, I'd like for it to look presentable on both versions. What is the standard way of designing for this? Do I include the highest res shots possible for the 3, and then let it scale down in software when rendered on lower versions? Do I include two versions of every image? Do I include just the highest resolution that the 2 can render, and hope for the best on the 3?